# How to Show count of Message in the inbox in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am making an inbox module i want to show message count on a label. data is coming from server. so if we have 30 messages the label will show 30 messages. how it can be done? do push notification concept will use here or something else?

Comment: r u using this method in inside the app

Comment: means ??? Method inside the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the one `UILablel` via programmatically or using `IBOutlet` and set the `frame` where u want to apply, finally set like

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30)]; //change the frame size as you need
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.bounds.size.height / 2;
label.TextAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourarrayname.count];  // here add your message array name
label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

**Swift**

```
let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30))//change the frame size as you need
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.bounds.size.height / 2
label.TextAlignment = .Center
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
label.text = "\(yourarrayname.count)" // here add your message array name
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view!.addSubview(label)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: will let you know after checking it.. :) matches with my criteria :)